# how to mock the abstract class constructor

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am not able to mock the constructor in the abstract class. Getting NPE when it tries to read `System.getenv("SOME_ENV")`. I tried so many combinations like `@spy`, `@Mock`, setting variables and tried adding different runners but no luck. Can someone please help?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

public abstract class AbstractClass {
    private String x;

    public AbstractClass(){
    try {
      x = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(System.getenv("SOME_ENV"))));
       }
     catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

//ConcrteClass.java

```
 class ConcrteClass extends AbstractClass {

    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("from sub class");
    }
}
```

//ConcrteClassTest.java

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ System.class, ConcrteClass.class, AbstractClass.class })
public class ConcrteClassTest {
    @Mock
    ConcrteClass concrteClass;

    @BeforeEach
    public void test() {
    PowerMockito.when(System.getenv(Mockito.eq("SOME_ENV"))).thenReturn("xyz");
    }
    @Test
    public void testMethod(){
       concrteClass = new ConcrteClass();
     }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, there is no setenv method in System class

Comment: Better approach: Don't bury crazy initialization like this in a constructor (a constructor that swallows exceptions!).

Comment: Ok.which is the best place toi initialize such things?

Comment: Somewhere completely separate, and then pass `x` as a plain string to the constructor. Where "completely separate" is depends on your environment (for example, with a Spring project, using Spring configuration settings is usually the best option).

Comment: It is actually a password which will be read from containers in the non-local environments. so the idea was not to send this variable from every class/method and also not to configure somewhere in the settings